# Cannot Create Hotspot on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: hot-spot

I have been able to create a hotspot successfully using a VivoBook E203M previously, but I now have a replacement E203M and it fails as follows:

"Network - Requesting a WiFi network address for 'MyHotspot'"

If I attempt to connect another device to MyHotspot it connects but eventually gives up and reports "Failed to obtain IP address"

Using Xubuntu 22.04.1 LTS now, I think I was using Xubuntu 20.04 previously on the other VivoBook

Any suggestions very welcome

```
paul@VivoBook:~$ ifconfig wlo1
wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>mtu 1500
inet 10.42.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.42.0.255
inet6 2a02:810b:169f:edde::1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
inet6 fe80::fdb7:e1c6:aa71:fd55  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
ether 84:c5:a6:76:c5:37  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
RX packets 155056  bytes 208321248 (208.3 MB)
RX errors 0  dropped 4  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 61828  bytes 9059940 (9.0 MB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I am not using hostapd, just the GUI to 'Create new wifi network' I have added the ifconfig results to the original question as the text was too long to add as a comment

MyHotspot settings thumbsnap.com/i/T6452yvs.gif

I have also tried using the command line to create a hotspot

```
nmcli device wifi hotspot ifname wlo1 ssid MyHotspot2 password "PASSWORD"
```

This has the same effect, the status is shown as

"Network - Requesting a WiFi network address for 'MyHotspot'"

I have now tried on a different LAN, and the same "Network - Requesting a WiFi network address for 'MyHotspot'" occurs

Comment: Hi ukkid35, I guess you use `hostapd` and `dhcpd` services? Does the `dhcpd`  run properly? If so please extend your question with the configuration files of these services and the output of  `ifconfig <wlaninterface>`

Comment: The several pieces of info you have added as comments should have been added with EDIT to the question. Comments are where you are asked to supply more info in order to help you. Not a place for more info.